# Automate Solving of customer technical issue Production L3 tickets

Tags: machine-learning, automation, nlp, prediction, google-prediction

I want to develop a app/software which understand text from various input and make Decision according to it. Further  if any point the system got confused then user  can  manual supply the output for it and from next time onwards system must learn to give such output in these scenarios. Basically system must learn from its past experience. The job that i want handle with this system is mundane job of resolving customer technical problems.( Production L3 tickets). The input in this case would be customer problem like with the order( like the state in which order is stuck and the state in which he wants it to be pushed) and second input be the current state order( data retrieved for that order from multiple tables of db) . For these two inputs the output would be the desired action to be taken like to update certain columns and fire XML for that order. The tools which I think would required is a Natural Language processor( NLP) library for understanding text and machine learning so as learn from past confusing scenarios.

Comment: This question is asking the SO community to design an application for you, thus much too broad a question.

Comment: I am asking a road map for developing this application. Like suppose if I start developing this thing  with java, then what libraries and what tools will be require to process & interpret text input. Basically any Natural language processing engine to interpret customer problem text and  then I can code output base on this customer input and data from DB for that order in which customer seeks problem. Then I need to know what Machine Learning engine I must use to let my application learn from my manually provide output of sets of input in which application was unable to predict  output .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use Java libraries for your NLP Pipeline, have a look at [Opennlp](https://opennlp.apache.org/documentation/1.6.0/manual/opennlp.html).

you've a lot of basic support [here](http://self-learning-java-tutorial.blogspot.in/2015/10/opennlp-sentence-detector-training.html).

And then you've [deeplearning4j](http://deeplearning4j.org/lstm.html) where you've a lot of Neural Network implementations in java. 
As you want a Dynamic model which can learn from past experiences rather than a static one, you've a number of neural netwrok implementations which you can play with in deeplearning4j.

Hope this helps!